# Cannot convert json

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I'm trying to convert `flask` request to `json`

```
from flask import request
import json

req_data = request.get_json(force=True)
json_data = json.dumps(req_data)
json.loads(json_data)
```

But when I try this I have :

`TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable`

Can you explain me ?

Comment: Have you checked the mimetype of the request? Is it application/json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `json.dumps` serialize `obj` to a `JSON` formatted `str` using [conversion table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table)

To extend this to recognize other objects, subclass [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) class and implement a [`default()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) method with another method that returns a serializable object for `o` if possible.

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> class SetEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, o):
...             if isinstance(o, set):
...                     # Do your serailzation here...
...             return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

Then you could do `json.dumps(obj, cls=SetEncoder)`.

For example,

```
>>> import json
>>> my_obj = {1: {1,2, 3}}
>>>
>>> class SetEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, o):
...         if isinstance(o, set):
...             return list(o)
...         return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
...
>>> print(json.dumps(my_obj, cls=SetEncoder))
{"1": [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `set` type is not serializable to JSON. You'll need to convert it to something like a `list` first:

```py
from flask import request
import json

req_data = request.get_json(force=True)
json_data = json.dumps(list(req_data))
json.loads(json_data)
```

[Repl.it example](https://repl.it/@rakenodiax/OpulentNaturalGnuassembler)